# Opening and keeping the window on PySide6

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm trying to convert a program into a mac app via pyside6. The program gets input about assignment names, dates, scores, percentage it takes in total, and calculates the total score. The program(in python) works fine, but I'm trying to convert into app, and am stuck. When running my program, the window does pop out but instantly closes after opening, and I cannot input in it as it closes right after opening.

The input on my program is a bit strange, but it's because it's adjusted to my school's website.

The original program code:

```
raw_grade = []
indexes = []
index = 0
score = []
percent = []
fi_score = []
raw = []
add = 0
denom = 0
total = 0
import sys
import re
from operator import itemgetter
print("Enter the data")

def multi_input():
    try:
        while True:
            data=input()
            if not data: break
            yield data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

data = list(multi_input())

for i in range(3, len(data),4):
    index = i
    indexes.append(i)

raw_grade = [data[id] for id in indexes]

for i in range(len(raw_grade)):
    gc = raw_grade[i].split('\t')
    raw.append(gc)

for i in range(len(raw)):
    percent.append(raw[i][3])
    score.append(raw[i][4])

for i in range(len(score)):
    use_score = score[i].split('/')
    fi_score.append(use_score)

score = fi_score

score = [value for value in score if value != ['']]


for i in range(len(score)):
    score[i] = [float(i) for i in score[i]]

for i in range(len(score)):
    try:
        score[i] = score[i][0]/score[i][1]100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 0

for i in range(len(percent)):
    try:
        percent[i] = percent[i].replace('%', '')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 0

percent = [value for value in percent if value != '']

for i in range(len(percent)):
    try:
        percent = [float(i) for i in percent]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 0

print("graded assignments: ", len(score))

#calculation part
for i in range(len(score)):
    add = score[i]percent[i]/100
    total = total + add
    denom = denom + percent[i]

total = total/denom*100
print(f"{total:05.2f}")
```

What I've worked on so far:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
raw_grade = []
indexes = []
index = 0
score = []
percent = []
fi_score = []
raw = []
add = 0
denom = 0
total = 0
import sys
import re
from operator import itemgetter


def multi_input(self):
    try:
        while True:
            self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
            self.nameLabel.setText('Name:')
            self.line = QLineEdit(self)
            if not self.line.text(): break
            yield self.line.text()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        raw_grade = []
        indexes = []
        index = 0
        score = []
        percent = []
        fi_score = []
        raw = []
        add = 0
        denom = 0
        total = 0

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Line Edit example (textfield) - pythonprogramminglanguage.com")

        multi_input(self)
        self.line = list(multi_input(self))


        pybutton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 60)

        for i in range(3, len(self.line), 4):
            index = i
            indexes.append(i)

        raw_grade = [self.line[id] for id in indexes]

        score = fi_score

        score = [value for value in score if value != ['']]

        for i in range(len(raw_grade)):
            gc = raw_grade[i].split('\t')
            raw.append(gc)

        for i in range(len(raw)):
            percent.append(raw[i][3])
            score.append(raw[i][4])

        for i in range(len(score)):
            use_score = score[i].split('/')
            fi_score.append(use_score)



        for i in range(len(score)):
            score[i] = [float(i) for i in score[i]]

        for i in range(len(score)):
            try:
                score[i] = score[i][0] / score[i][1] * 100
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                result = 0

        for i in range(len(percent)):
            try:
                percent[i] = percent[i].replace('%', '')
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                result = 0

        percent = [value for value in percent if value != '']

        for i in range(len(percent)):
            try:
                percent = [float(i) for i in percent]
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                result = 0

        print("graded assignments: ", len(score))

        # calculation part
        for i in range(len(score)):
            add = score[i] * percent[i] / 100
            total = total + add
            denom = denom + percent[i]

        self.line = total / denom * 100
        print('Your name: ' + self.line.text())
    def clickMethod(self):
        print('Your name: ' + self.line.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Your code has various issues, with the first causing the crash by a zero division error (since `denom` is 0). Always run your code in a terminal or prompt to see the full traceback of errors, which some IDEs are not able to provide (assuming you *are* using an IDE, which you should). Even commenting that line won't suffice, since you'll get an attribute error caused by the fact that `self.line` (which was created more than once and with a terrible approach) was overwritten with a list, which clearly doesn't have a `text` attribute.

Comment: sry it's my first time using pyside, and I'm not that well experienced with python either. Thx for the comment anyways, I'll try to improve my code accordingly.

Comment: Don't worry, everybody has been a beginner :-) Just keep in mind that the scope of StackOverflow is to provide a "shared knowledge" Q&A website: while I can relate to your needs, writing in the question that you're a beginner (or, especially, that you're in a hurry) won't get you better or "faster" results; actually, most of the times you just get the opposite, as people that provide answers are not interested in "being the first": there are questions here that get answers **years** after being posted. The scope of SO is to give *good* answers, not fast ones: this is not a help-desk.